# Conditions for Newton's method to converge.

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I would like to know some, easy to use,  conditions for Newton's method to converge. I know a condition that states that the method will converge for a function $f(x)$  If for an interval $[a, b]$ it is true that $$f(a)<0<f(b)$$ $$f'(x) >0$$ and $$f''(x) >0$$, but I would like to know how can I find $[a, b]$, should I do this by trial and error?  And how can I generally use this method?

Comment: What conditions, for instance on the wikipedia page, have you already found? What about them did you not understand?

Comment: I have found the following condition for the method to converge for  $f(x)$ . If $$f(a)<0<f(b)$$  $$f'(x) >0$$ and $$f''(x) >0$$ then the method converges for $[a, b]$. But how can I find this interval $[a, b]$? Generally how can I use this?

Comment: Please put substantial information into the question text. You may then put a notification of the change in the comments.

Comment: You can't really use this, as finding such an interval is as difficult as finding the root. However, the condition, and its variants by sign changes, tells you that if the function is not oscillating too wildly then trying random initial points has a good probability of landing in such an interval.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases we can prove that $f'(x)>0$ and $f''(x)\geq  0$ for all $x$ without knowing anything about $a$ and $b.$ Then we may be able to prove there exists $a, b$ with $f(a)<0<f(b)$. In this case you can begin the iteration anywhere.

In practice a less restrictive but sufficient set of conditions is

(i).  There exists $c$ with $f(c)=0.$

(ii).There exist $a>c$ (the same $c$ as in (i)) such that $f(a)>0$ and such that $f'(x)>0$ for $c<x\leq a.$

(iii). $f'$ is increasing  on $(c,a).$ (That is, $c<x<y<a\implies f'(x)\leq f'(y)$ .)

For a non-linear function $f,$ condition (i), (ii) and (iii) imply that $f(x)>0$ for $c<x\leq a$ and that the sequence $a_{n+1}=a_n-f(a_n)/f'(a_n),$ with $a_1=a,$ is strictly decreasing and remains in $(c,a]$ so it has a limit $d,$ and that $f(d)=0$ (so $d=c$).

Example. Let $f(x)=x^4-10.$ We know there exists $c\in (0,2)$ with $f(c)=0$ because $f(0)<0<f(2)$. We have $f'(x)=4x^3 >0$ for $x>0$,  hence $f'(x)>0$ for $x>c.$  We have $f''(x)=12x^2\geq 0$ , hence  $f'$ is increasing for $x>c.$ So we can begin an iteration with $a=a_1=2.$